# Use an external javascript dictionary file to inject HTML into span

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I am implementing a simple site filter using keywords. The user types a keyword into the search field and the DOM updates based on keyword matches. This is already working but I'd like to not code the keywords directly into the HTML, I'd prefer to have an external 'dictionary' file that loads the keywords into the HTML based on the id#.

So what I have is something like:

```
 <div id="23">
 <span="keywords" style="display:none">list,of,keywords,goes,here</span>
 </div>
```

I'd like to have some jQuery or Javascript that reads an external file something like:

```
  var dictionary = {
  "23": ["list","of","key","words"], 
  "24": ["different","list","goes","here"]
   };
```

Having all the keywords in an external list like this will make it much easier to maintain. I'm pretty sure I need to inject innerHTML on the keyword span but I'm not sure of the next steps.

Edit: I should mention that the sort filter I'm using requires the keywords to actually be present in the HTML. I basically need to write out the html as I did above. I would just like the list of words/ids to be in a separate, easy to edit file.

Comment: Why not just use a HTTP get on a JSON file with your dictionary of words? In JQuery you're looking for the $.ajax function. In vanilla JS you're looking for the XMLHttpRequest API.

Comment: Why not use a separate JS file and include it in your script tags?

Comment: Thanks @zfrisch - that's the route I was thinking, I'm just not sure how I would implement that. Would I do call a function onload that wrote out all the spans?  I'm using a sort library already which requires my keywords to actually be in the HTML to work.

Comment: I've come up with a solution below, which works, but wondering if it's the right way to go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've got an answer, and it works and does everything I wanted it to do - but that leads to another question: Is this a good way to go about this?

In my HTML I put: (1 for each of a hundred or so divs)

```
   <span class="keys" id="keywords_101" style="display:none"></span>
```

This is what will become my comma separated list of keywords I need for my filter plugin:

The JS:

```
 var fruitlist = {
  "103": ["apples","bananas","pears"],
  "102": ["dates","kiwis","mangos"],
  "101": ["passion fruit","watermelon","grapes"],
  "100": ["oranges","tangerines","lychee"]
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
Object.size = function(obj) {
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};

var size = Object.size(fruitlist); 

for (var n=0; n < size; n++) { 
  var track_key = Object.keys(fruitlist)[n];
  var keyword = fruitlist[track_key];
  for (var i=0; i < fruitlist[track_key].length;i++ ) {
  document.getElementById('keywords_'+track_key).innerHTML=keyword;
   }
  }
});
```

So this all works now. But is there a simpler/better/more efficient way to do this rather than looping through a fruitlist of 100+ items and writing the divs?

I could honestly just hardcode the divs into the HTML but I forsee editing the keyword lists quite a bit and having them broken out of the HTML in an easy to access/edit format is appealing.

Thanks

Comment: I see I've received a down vote for my answer, which of course isn't helpful unless there's an explanation. I'm marking this as the answer because it works - unless someone can come up with reason why it should be done a different way.